# jQuery UI: - Switch Class but add a hover effect?

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery code to add a class to "p" tags within an "li" when you hover over them... but how can i make this more interesting by adding a transition effect rather than just a straight switch?

code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').hover(function() {
        $('p', this).toggleClass('hovered');
    });
});
```

Comment: When you say "add a fade effect" do you mean the element should "fade in" (was invisible, turns visible slowly) or just that the class transition should be smooth (ex.: the class properties "drift" from initial class' values from final class' ones)?

Comment: Yes, the transition should be smooth... like fade from Red to blue..without going black first... currently the solutions below seem to go black first.

Comment: Updated my answer, it should behave like you stated now. Most people look confused by the use of the word **fade**, since it implies you wanted the element to disappear/appear at some point. I suggested an edit replacing this expression for "transition effect", ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function, you can animate the transition between two classes.

Edit: sorry, wrong method. What you're looking for is the [switchClass](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/ClassTransitions) method.

Here's a [demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/switchClass/) of the switchClass. It's useful if you have two classes, and want to switch from one to the other. If you just want to add/remove a single class, see Wouter J's answer.

**Update**: It seems you'll need two classes for this to work. Also note that switchClass requires jQuery UI to work. Here's an example:

HTML:

```
<li>
    <p class="regular">Test</p>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
p.regular { color:red }
p.hovered { color:blue }
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').hover(function() {
        $('p', this).switchClass('regular','hovered', 2000);
    },function() {
        $('p', this).switchClass('hovered','regular', 2000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Almost...it doesn't revert back to "regular" when you hover off it... any ideas?

Comment: @CodeyMonkey Sure! `hover` accepts an additional function to be run when the hover ends. Answer updated.

Comment: Great - ok lastly....the fade is a bit nasty..e.g. jumpy... even when set at 100 or 200...how can I change the default effect please?

Comment: I'm not actually experienced in effects, but there's some nice demos [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/#easing). See the docs I posted for switchClass, you can specify the transition easing as the 4th argument.

Answer (score 1):

```
var clone = $("<p>");
$('div').hover(
    function() {
           clone.remove();
           clone = $("p", this).clone();
           $("p", this).after(clone);
           clone
                .hide()
                .css({
                    position: "absolute",
                    top: $("p", this).offset().top,
                    left: $("p", this).offset().left,
                    width: $("p", this).width(),
                    height: $("p", this).height(),
                    "z-index": 2
                })
                .addClass("hovered")
                .fadeIn();
    },
    function() {
           clone
                .fadeOut("normal", function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi, This goes black/disapears then fades to the right class, any chance this can work without the diapearing bit first?

Comment: The text disapears and it jumps to black, it needs to be a smooth transition. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are using jQuery UI, so you can use [`.toggleClass( class, duration )`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggleClass/), where duration is the duration of the fade:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li').hover(function() {
    $('p', this).toggleClass('hovered', 1000); // 1000ms = 1s
  });
});
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work...

$(document).ready(function() {
$('li').hover(function() {
  $('p', this).toggleClass('hovered', 500);
});
});

Answer (score 0):

try this, you can even `add` more `effect` by adding `options` in `fedeIn` and `fadeOut`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li').hover(function() {
    $('p', this).fadeIn(function(){
      $(this).addClass('hovered');
    });
  },function(){
    $('p', this).fadeOut(function(){
      $(this).removeClass('hovered');
    });
  });
});
```